# Expand json column in PySpark - schema issues - AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using pyspark to extract data from a mutli-line json object. I am able to read in the file but I am unable to parse out the contents of the geometry column.

An example of the overall table is shown below.

```
+--------------------+--------------------+-------+
|            geometry|          properties|   type|
+--------------------+--------------------+-------+
|{[13.583336, 37.2...|{AGRIGENTO, AGRIG...|Feature|
|{[13.584538, 37.3...|{AGRIGENTO, AGRIG...|Feature|
|{[13.657838, 37.3...|{FAVARA, AGRIGENT...|Feature|
|{[13.846247, 37.3...|{CANICATTÃŒ, AGRI...|Feature|
|{[13.616626, 37.4...|{ARAGONA, AGRIGEN...|Feature|
|{[13.108426, 37.6...|{SAMBUCA DI SICIL...|Feature|
|{[16.709313, 41.0...|{GRUMO APPULA, BA...|Feature|
|{[12.670994, 41.4...|{NETTUNO, ROMA, 6...|Feature|
|{[12.501805, 42.1...|{CASTELNUOVO DI P...|Feature|
|{[12.608105, 41.4...|{ANZIO, ROMA, b54...|Feature|
+--------------------+--------------------+-------+
```

This is the format of a single line of the json geometry column

```json
"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[13.583336,37.270182]}
```

and when I extract the schema this is what it looks like

```
StructType(List(StructField("geometry",StructType(List(StructField("coordinates",ArrayType(DoubleType,true),true),StructField("type",StringType,true))),true)
```

However, when I try and set up the schema in PySpark to import the data I am getting the following error.

> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'name'

This is the code I am using.

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StructType, StringType, FloatType, ArrayType, DoubleType
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.read.option("multiLine", False).option("mode", "PERMISSIVE").json('Italy/it_countrywide-addresses-country.geojson')


schema = StructType([
    (StructField("coordinates",
                 ArrayType(DoubleType())),
     StructField("type",StringType()))
])

df.withColumn("geometry", F.from_json("geometry", schema)).select(col('geometry.*')).show()
```

I welcome your comments.

Comment: I have not answered the question but found a way around it. Import the file twice (must be a better way) and grab schema on one of these imports and use it as an argument on the second import.

`json_schema = spark.read.option("multiLine", False).option("mode", "PERMISSIVE").json('Italy/it_countrywide-addresses-country.geojson').schema
df_with_schema = spark.read.option("multiLine", False).option("mode", "PERMISSIVE").schema(json_schema).json('Italy/it_countrywide-addresses-country.geojson')
df_with_schema.printSchema()
coordinates = df_with_schema.select(F.col('geometry.coordinates'))`

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question if you have a working solution. It might help others and won't prevent people from providing "better" answers.

Comment: The error is saying you have extra `(` inside the StructType array.  `StructType` should be array of `StructField` and not tuple.

Comment: @Emma thanx ! you saved my a$$ I was going nut with this ^^

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, my goal was to read in the json file and access the nested values. The error I was receiving was down to me not creating the schema correctly. The best way to correct this error is to avoid manually creating the schema.

To do this I used the schema that you can create by calling .schema on the json file. This resolves any problems of creating the schema yourself.

The downside of this is that you are effectively importing the file twice, no doubt this can be further optimised to avoid this.

```
json_schema = spark.read.option("multiLine", False).option("mode", "PERMISSIVE").json('Italy/it_countrywide-addresses-country.geojson').schema 
df_with_schema = spark.read.option("multiLine", False).option("mode", "PERMISSIVE").schema(json_schema).json('Italy/it_countrywide-addresses-country.geojson') 
df_with_schema.printSchema() 

# Select coordinates array
coordinates = df_with_schema.select(F.col('geometry.coordinates'))

# select single value from coordinates array
single_value_from_coordinates_array = df_with_schema.select(F.col('geometry.coordinates')[0])

# create my own dataframe choosing multiple columns from json file
multi_columns = df_with_schema.select(F.col('geometry.coordinates'), F.col('properties.city'))
```